# Is it possible to re-call a successful jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Let's say I have a set of selectors being passed in and then if one of them is successful, I want to re-check for that selector again but underneath a top-level element and then run an event on that if found. So...

```
$('element1, element2, element3').click(function() {
    $('#header' + successfulElement).addClass('active');
    });
```

Then, if the user hits any one of those `elements` (there could be multiple throughout the document) we check to see if an element with the same selector is underneath `#header`.

Does that make sense? It sounds complicated, but I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something fundamental here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a generic way to find out which part of a selector matched a given element, but if your selectors have a specific form, you could exploit certain properties. For example, if each `elementN` is a HTML tag, you could use `this.tagName` to recover the matched tag:

```
$('element1, element2, element3').click(function() {
  $('#header ' + this.tagName).addClass('active');
});
```

Similarly, you could use `this.className` to get the class name(s) of the clicked element.

---

**Update:** Since your selectors are quite complex, the only way out might be to bind individual handlers for each sub-selector. You can automatically generate these handlers like this:

```
function bindClick(selector) {
  $(selector).click(function() {
    $('#header ' + selector).addClass('active');
  });
}

var selectors = [ 'a[href*="/el1"]', 'a[href*="/el2"]', 'a[href*="/el3"]' ];
for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++)
  bindClick(selectors[i]);
```

Comment: But that would seem to affect all elements under `#header` with the same tag or class. I think OP just wants the clicked one.

Comment: @patrick dw: I believe that's what the OP wants -- "I want to re-check for that selector again but underneath a top-level element". As I understand it, an element outside `#header` is clicked and he wants to find a similar element inside `#header`.

Comment: @casablanca: Yes, I can see how it could be interpreted that way. You may be right. +1

Comment: Correct logic, but it won't work unfortunately, because my selectors are rather complex. `a[href*="/el1"], a[href*="/el2"], a[href*="/el3"]` is the actual selector—so it's checking for any link in the document that contains `/el1`, `/el2` or `/el3` and then the idea is that it will mark the relevant section as `class="active"` in the header.

Comment: @Chris Sealey: See my updated answer for a different approach.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks so much, @casablanca. That's worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('element1, element2, element3').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.closest("#header").length)
        $this.addClass('active');
});
```

You can also use `parents()`, but `closest()` does the same job except it stops when it reaches a matching element (so it performs better).

Answer (score 0):

Can you side step the issue entirely by giving the elements in question some kind of commonality (eg using a shared data- attribute) then doing the below?

```
$("selector1, selector2, selector3").bind("click", activate);

function activate(e){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("[data-id='" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "']",
        $("header")).addClass("active").trigger("some event");
}
```